# Passing parameters to my docker container

Tags: c#, docker-compose, dockerfile, visual-studio-2017

Here is what I have done:

1. Create a new standard .Net C# console project

   ```
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       foreach (var arg in args)
           Console.WriteLine(arg);
   }
   ```
2. Rightclick on the project and select Add->Docker Support
3. Edit the project's dockerfile and change its ENTRYPOINT:

   ```
   ENTRYPOINT ["C:\app\ConsoleApp1.exe", "Hello", "World"]
   ```
4. Set a breakpoint and Run

`args` is empty.

`docker-compose` did emit my entrypoint during the build:

```
1>Step 5/5 : ENTRYPOINT ["C:\app\ConsoleApp1.exe", "Hello", "World"]
```

What am I missing?

Comment: FWIW, I am using the private build of docker-compose mentioned here: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4710

Answer (score -1):

You can get the command line arguments this way:

```
    Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
```

This works also in a Docker container.